# I want to merge dat and dml and convert it into an Excel format

Tags: python

Sample below data(.dat)

```
Sweta|dhanbad|1000|1
Manish|dhanbad|2000|2
Priyanka|dhanbad|3000|3
```

and below dml file(.dml) I want to use as a file

```
record
string("|") name /* VARCHAR(10)*/;
string("|") address; // VARCHAR(40)
decimal("|") salary;
integer("\n") I'd;
end
```

I want to merge this dml in dat file I want to convert it into an Excel format where first row should come as proper field name and in 2nd row data type for each field should come suppose data type is integer("\n") then this should populate below I'd column and so on

Below code till now I have tried but whatever I tried in that field name is coming with data type but I want it in 2nd row of that excel

```
import pandas as pd
dml_file = 'src.dml'
with open(dml_file, "r") as dml:
    dml_lines = dml.readlines()
col = []
for line in dml_lines[1:-1]:
    if line:
        col.append(line.strip(';').strip())
```

Can anyone please help? what modification I need to do to achieve data type in 2nd row

Target excel i want in below format
[image]

Comment: Please add the desired Excel file to the question.

Comment: Hi @СергейКох, added.

Comment: It's not clear what your specific difficulty is?